# How to fill forms with cakePHP

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, view, controller

I'm using cakePHP v2.4 and I'm trying to automatically fill a form.
What I do in my controller is this:

```
$contact = $this->Contact->findById($id);
$this->set('data', $contact);
```

And in my view I use de formHelper like this:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Person');
echo $this->Form->text('firstname', array('label' => 'Firstname'));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

I would like my input firstname to be automatically filled with the value I obtained from  my request. This is what I get when I do pr($data) in my view:

```
Array
(
[Contact] => Array
    (
        [id] => 15
        [created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [modified] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [type] => person
    )

[Person] => Array
    (
        [contact_id] => 15
        [firstname] => eric
    )
)
```

As you can see, I have a table 'Contact' and depending on the type , whether it's 'person' or 'firm' I will load the corresponding table.
I don't know what I'm missing here and I didn't find the answer yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `$this->request->data = $contact;`, and that should only be done on GET requests in case you are posting the form data back to the same action:

```
if($this->request->is('post'))
{
    // process the posted form data
}
else
{
    $this->request->data = $this->Contact->findById($id);
}
```

Use the [bake shell](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html) to generate models/controllers/views and learn from that code. Also check the cookbook: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html#editing-posts

Comment: Perfect, I did $this->request->data = $this->Contact->findById($id) and it works :) thank you !